# Jquery image gallery images zoom when its hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, gallery

I have image gallery created with using jquery. I want to create, when I hover some image it will zoom and others will zoom out. I attached sample image of my gallery.

How can I create a gallery like that?
Please help.

[image]

Comment: share your code what you tried?

Comment: Have you tried any code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm thinking of "layer over layer" so that mouse hover could work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Jquery you can use Boostrap for Responsive Image Gallery
Try this link: https://miketricking.github.io/bootstrap-image-hover/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want to create selected or hover image scale up and rest of images are scale down relatively.

Comment: Try this link also:(https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/Best-Image-Zoom-jQuery-Plugins.html)  ,( https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-image-zoomers/ )